# Surface plot error

Tags: python, plot

[image]
I've tried to google how to do this but can't seem to get it to work. Any help or suggestions are greatly appreciated. Here is what I've tried from googling but assume I'm just not doing it right

```
import numpy as np

import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

def prob_10(x,y):
    return x*np.exp(-x**2/2-y**3/3+y)

fig = plt.figure()
ax = fig.add_subplot(projection='3d')
x = y = np.arange(-3.0, 3.0, 0.05)
X, Y = np.meshgrid(x, y)
z = prob_10(x,y)
```

keep getting this error 
matplotlib.figure.Figure at 0x7fa34fd9c310

Comment: I doubt that you get an error, you are not plotting anything at all :-)

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

(You may find plot_surface more useful and you may want to set limits to you axes. For more examples have a look here: http://matplotlib.org/gallery.html#mplot3d)

```
import numpy as np
from mpl_toolkits.mplot3d import Axes3D
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

fig = plt.figure()
ax = fig.add_subplot(111, projection='3d')
c='r'
m='o'
x = np.arange(-3.0, 3.0, 0.05)
y = np.arange(-3.0, 3.0, 0.05)
X,Y = np.meshgrid(x, y)
Z = X*np.exp(-X**2/2-Y**3/3+Y)
ax.scatter(X, Y, Z, c=c, marker=m)
#ax.plot_surface(X, Y, Z) 

plt.show()
```

Scatter Plot:

[image: Scatter Plot]

Plot_Surface:

[image: Plot_Surface]